# HTML div overlapping with the footer

Tags: css, layout, html, styling

I keep staring with firebug at this page:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=54603

and I can't figure out why the right side is overlapping with the bottom div.  It might be because it is past midnight for me, but could anyone tell what is going wrong there?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the

```
height:325px;
```

in the containing `div`, that comes after `<!-- End of photos from this park -->`. Note that it's always a bad idea to manually add `style` information to HTML, you should rather use classes for that.

---

Also, some of the syntax looks garbled:

```
<div width:400px;">
```

should be:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
```

Comment: +1. Was just about to post the same thing. Curse my slow fingers! :D

Comment: Heh ;) See my updates, something looks wrong with the tags, are they autogenerated?

Answer (score 0):

You have a DIV with a height set of 325px;

```
<div style="height:325px; width:400px;">
    <p></p><h2>Hikes Coming Up In The Area</h2><p></p>
.....
```

Removing the height or setting overflow:hide/scroll in CSS will fix this.